# How to submit form using Ajax in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am getting problem to save my form data in the database.  I am done small code on that which is shown below, when i enter data in form and click on my submit button it not work.

```js
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 var form = $("#frm");

 $.ajax({
  url: '/Form/Index',
  data: form.serialize(),
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {
        }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" id="frm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" style="color:black;">Product Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
                        placeholder="Product Name" style="color:black;">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" style="color:black;">Product Date</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text1"
                    placeholder="Date" style="color:black;">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" style="color:black;">Product Price</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Text2"
                    placeholder="Date" style="color:black;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="ok" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

Above is my code please give me solution on that

Comment: Place your button inside form. Also, always specify the type attribute for a <button> element. Different browsers use different default types for the <button> element.

Comment: In what way isn't it working?

Comment: No first i use that submit button inside the form but not working so i try it using outside.

Comment: share the file path of file to which data has to be submitted,if possible.

Comment: See your updated code.

Comment: one form contain certain field when i enter text  on that and click the submit button it should be store but problem on that it not store in the databse, I have done databse code for see that databse i want one entry but in not working

Comment: have you tried putting breakpoint in your C# function?

Answer (score 0):

As I've checked you code, client side code is working fine, The only problem I can imagine in this case is you `url path`.

- make sure you are providing correct `url path`.
- You should check if its hitting the that page or not.

Comment: IF possible please provide you file path.

Answer (score 0):

Which Framework you are using. Different framework has different syntax to pass the value in URL. Check the path you are getting in the page source page view in URL parameter or you can check the error in console log after the submit. It may be not getting the correct path of your action.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the type="submit" from button**

You have to get the form submit with id and serialize the form data
`

```
$("#formid").submit(function(e) {
var url = "urlpathtohandlerequest"; 

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#formid").serialize(), 
       success: function(response)
       {
           alert(response); 
       }
     });

e.preventDefault(); // stops default submit.
});
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ajax library loaded successfully, and try to have alert messages to have forward step where you reached, have this test:

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $("#frm");

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Form/Index',
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
             alert('before send alert')
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
             alert(error);
        },
    });
});
```

if beforeSend not executed so your issue is related to ajax library.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$("#ok").click(function(e) {
 // your code 
}
```

Refer to id in javascript rather than class attribute.
If you refer class attribute than once it has click javascript perform preventDefault on that class so that if not refresh your page, The button is not working.

Put preventDefault function at last of your function.